Where does JS runtime gets executed for Android app created in React Native?
As we know in React Native, the JS runtime is used to execute the JS code.
In Android the JS runtime is bundled with the Apk, and the Android system creates a process to run the Apk.
My question is:
Where does the JS runtime gets executed in the process, does it gets executed inside the DVM or somewhere else (some thread maybe) in the process?
